# Can I use my Canonical/Ubuntu.com or Launchpad account to post and / or answer questions here as well?

Tags: discussion, login

Can I use my Canonical/Ubuntu.com or Launchpad account to post and / or answer questions here as well?

I use the same name on Launchpad.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can. The whole network of StackExchange sites supports OpenID logins and since Launchpad provides OpenID login facility, you can use it to register an account here.

After following the Login link, you have the possibility to select an Open ID provider. Launchpad is one of them. Simply press the Launchpad button, enter your Launchpad username and hit *Sign In*.

[image: Login form]

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks. I was about to add snippets to my answer. But you were faster...

Comment: I was about to add an answer with that picture, but you were faster :P