# Migrated posts can be voted twice

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, migration

I remember to have upvoted the question and answer https://askubuntu.com/q/97569/6969 and after migration to meta I thought, *good question and answer, let's upvote it*.

After that, I realized that I've **already** voted those posts before as I can see on the main site. These upvotes are added to the previous ones as can be seen on [Can I use my Canonical/Ubuntu.com or Launchpad account to post and / or answer questions here as well?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2360/6969)

Comment: Related: [Reset votes on migrated question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As often, this has been noticed for a long time on other sites: [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user).

[Jeff's answer that this is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20210) makes zero sense to me.

I would in fact prefer to [reset votes on migrated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions), which would make this bug moot.

Comment: I'd see it being resetted as well. The arguments for resetting in both your answer as Aarthi' linked post are very valid.